# How to fill in a polygon with a lot of holes in it? Arcmap 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I have a lake map layer that mistook algae for land and now some of my lakes have a a lot of hole in them and I don't want these holes. I also don't want to delete Islands and I have a lot of lakes.

Comment: You could edit the layer with AutoComplete that would simplify the fill and merge together the filled holes with the existing lake. OR you could set up a topology and use the 'Must Not Have Gaps' rule which will fill the holes and you can select all and merge to make a single lake poly.

Comment: I want to do it on a lake by lake basis.

Comment: Could you obtain a different lake map layer without the holes?

Comment: No, I only have the one layer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Union](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//00080000000s000000) and then make sure the **"Gaps Allowed (Optional)"** check box is unchecked.

This will fill in any instances of 'holes' within a polygon layer.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [help document](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/filling-in-holes-in-polygons.htm):

> 1. Click the Edit tool on the Editor toolbar and double-click the feature you want to edit.
> 2. Right-click the part you want to delete, point to Part, then click Delete.
> 3. Right-click anywhere on the map and click Finish Sketch.

Answer (score 2):

You could [edit the vertices](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#//001t00000097000000.htm) of the polygon, then delete all vertices of the holes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a patch in an edit session. Draw a polygon that covers the holes, but does not extend past the lakeshore. You then merge the patch with the lake and all the holes are filled in.  With this method, you can work with relatively low precision without negatively affecting your shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use `Eliminate Polygon Part` tool to fill in the gaps in the polygons in ArcGIS Pro.